# Angular2/Nativescript: Issues displaying content in a GridLayout in a ListView template

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am busy with a very basic Angular2/Nativescript app and trying to display a list of products in a grid layout inside a list view template...  for some reason when I test this the labels gets stacked ontop of each other as if it's a verticle stack view instead of a grid view...  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?  Is this even possible?  There doesn't seem to be too much content online about Grid Layouts with Angular2/Nativescript yet...  I saw in the javascript that the grod layout has to be imported from ui/layouts?  I didn't do that but i'm not trying to change the layout from the controller so didn't think it would be necessary.

My code:

**product.component.html:**

```
<ListView class="list-group" [items]="products">
<template let-item="product">
<StackView class="hr-dark"></StackView>
<GridLayout columns = "auto, auto, auto, auto" rows="auto, auto"  class="list-group-item">
<Label col="0" row="0" class="list-group-item-heading" text="Description"></Label>
<Label col="0" row="1" class="list-group-item-text" [text]="product?.Description"></Label>

<Label col="1" row="0" class="list-group-item-heading" text="POS Description"></Label>
<Label col="1" row="1" class="list-group-item-text" [text]="product?.POSDescription"></Label>

<Label col="2" row="0" class="list-group-item-heading" text="POS price"></Label>
<Label col="2" row="1" class="list-group-item-text" [text]="'R' + product?.POSPrice"></Label>

<Label col="3" row="0" class="list-group-item-heading" text="Stock On Hand"></Label>
<Label col="3" row="1" class="list-group-item-text" [text]="product?.StockOnHand"></Label>
</GridView>

</template>
</ListView>
```

**check barcodes.component.html:**

```
<StackLayout class="page">
  <Label class="h1 title m-x-auto" text="Check Barcodes"></Label>
  <Label class="body m-l-5" text="Scan Or Enter a barcode"></Label>
  <StackLayout class="form">    
    <StackLayout class="input-field">               
        <TextField class="input input-border" hint="Enter barcode" keyboardType="number" [(ngModel)]="textBarcode"></TextField>
    </StackLayout>
    <Button class="btn btn-primary m-x-5" *ngIf="textBarcode" text="Submit" (tap)="submitTextBarcode()"></Button> 
  </StackLayout>
  <Button class="btn btn-primary m-x-5" text="Scan" (tap)="scan()"></Button>

    //this is where I am trying to add the gridLayout (from the productComponent)...
    <product *ngIf="product"></product>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a useful comment but it's all I've got: I always define the rows first, then the columns in a GridLayout (you're doing columns first.. think of it as a HTML table where you have td nested in tr so you're defining rows first). Also, your GridLayout closing tag is wrong (GridView).

Comment: Thanks @Eddy Verbruggen every/any idea is much appreciated:)

Comment: Also, there is no StackView but StackLayout (unless it is custom made component) and from 2.4.x you can create one side border via CSS e.g. with border-width: 0 10 20 0; so no need to create the border with stack-layout.

Comment: Another thing is that the list-view template needs one root component (can;t have multiple elements on root level)

Comment: @Nick Iliev thanks that's very helpful.  i'm trying to replicate a table in a web app, so should this be possible?  To have a GridLayout in a ListView?  the only issue then will be the headers that will  get repeated...

Comment: Yes, absolutely possible. In the link below you can find basic examples for all kinds of list-views including some with Grids as templates https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/common-screens-category/lists-category/single-line-grouped/grouped-single-line.component.html#L60-L65

Comment: Over 10 different list--view examples are shown in this application https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng

Comment: Thanks will take a look